# How to enforce a unique constraint on an element collection with Ebean

Tags: ebean

I've been trying variations on this, but I can't seem to get Ebean to recognize the constraint.

```
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(schema = "participants", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"), uniqueConstraints = {
            //The presence of actual column names in this line is an unfortunate consequence of eBean and JPA annotations
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"integration_tag", "role_id"})
    })
    private final List<DefaultAccount> defaultIntegrationAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
```

For reference, here's DefaultAccount:

```
@Embeddable
public class DefaultAccount {
    @NotNull
    private final String integrationTag;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Account account;

    DefaultAccount(String integrationTag, Account account) {
        this.integrationTag = integrationTag;
        this.account = account;
    }

    public String getIntegrationTag() {
        return integrationTag;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
}
```

Oddly enough, everything works well if DefaultAccount is made to be an entity rather than an embeddable, but this just goes against the domain modelling and I'd really rather not go down that route unless I absolutely have to...

Answer (score 0):

In the limitations section of the Ebean documentation linked [here](https://ebean.io/docs/intro/limitations/), it says

> @Embeddable class does not support @OneToMany / @ElementCollection.
>
> As @Embeddable does not have identity the case of supporting collections gets ugly. At this stage there is no planned support for this.

And you have identified that changing the `DefaultAccount` to an entity resolves the problem, so I think you have already identified the solution.

Comment: And yet, having it as embeddable actually works, other than the recognition of the constraint...? (As an aside, that limitation is kind of meh, since strings don't have identity either, and they seem to work fine...)

Comment: `And yet, having it as embeddable actually works, other than the recognition of the constraint`...so it works, except when it doesn't :)

Comment: Pretty much, but the point here is about the migrations, not identity. That snippet of documentation is just terribly misleading. (Then again, EBean's documentation is... not its greatest strength, so to speak...)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a validation rule in the code or add an annotation to the `integrationTag` field in the `DefaultAccount` class to prevent duplicates in a list of `DefaultAccounts`

Using an annotation like `@Column(unique=true)` will automatically make sure that no two `DefaultAccounts` have the same `integrationTag` and `role_id` values.

You can also create a custom validation rule that checks for duplicates before saving the list, by creating an annotation, validator, and applying it to the list.

Just remember that Ebean may not automatically detect duplicate constraints in element collections, so it's best to test thoroughly before using it in production.

Comment: "In code" doesn't really do it for me, as it would have no impact on migration generation and keeping the database synchronized with the model. As for `@Column(unique=true)`, that also doesn't work, because that makes each column unique, whereas in the domain, only the actual combination is unique. Making each column unique would actually violate the domain design in a major way.

Comment: consider using a custom validation constraint as mentioned

Comment: but it would require handling database synchronization separately

Comment: Right. That goes against the architecture of the project, not to mention that EBean *will* generate invalid migrations if the database is out of sync with the model.xml files.